# react-native changes the properties of the elements in the array?

Tags: react-native, radio-button, react-native-flatlist

I have a `FlatList` and I want to implement a radio button.My idea is to change the selected property of an element in `this.state.data` to control it,but I am a newbie, I don't know how to change the property of an element in `this.state.data`.

Here is my code:

```
this.state = {
  data: [
    {
      month:1,
      price:18,
      selected:true
    },
    {
      month:3,
      price:48,
      selected:false
    },
    {
      month:12,
      price:128,
      selected:false
    },
  ],
};
```

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={({item, index, separators}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.radio(index,item)}>
    <View style={item.selected ? {borderWidth:3,borderColor:'#FFA371',borderRadius:15}:{}}>
      <View style={styles.itemDefalut}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", flex: 1 }}>
          <Text>
          Months
          </Text>
          <Text>{item.month} Months</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>${item.price}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
/>
```

```
radio(index,item) {
  for (var variable in this.state.data) {
    variable.selected = false;
  }
  item.selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first pass only **index** from onpress

```
onPress={() => this.radio(index)
```

then in **radio** function do something like this

```
radio = index => {
  let data = [ ...this.state.data ];
  this.state.data.map((elem,key)=>{
    if(elem.month==data[index].month){
       data[key]={...data[key], selected: true};
    }else{
     data[key]={...data[key], selected: false};
    }
  })
  this.setState({ data:data});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
radio(item) {
  let data = [...this.state.data]; 
  let index = data.findIndex(el => el.month === item.month); 
  data[index] = {...data[index], selected: !item.selected};
  this.setState({ data });
}
```

In TouchableOpacity on press it should be

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.radio.bind(this,item)}>
```